# Mastermind Text-based, not identifying correct numbers in password

Tags: python

My code does not properly count the correct digits,

Example: (Note, I printed the password on purpose (list))

```
    I've set my password, enter 5 digits in the range [1-9] (e.g. 9 3 2 4 7):

[1, 5, 6, 7, 8]
10  guesses remaining.
>
1 5 6 7 9
1  of 5 correct digits.
4  of 5 correct locations.
9  guesses remaining.
>
```

4 of the 5 digits are correct, counts only "1  of 5".

Here is my code:

```
import random

def generatePassword():
    '''Generates unique 5 digit password'''
    randomSetOfValues = set()
    while len(randomSetOfValues) < 5:
        randomSetOfValues.add(random.randint(1,9))
    return list(randomSetOfValues)

def getUserGuess():
    '''Gets users geuss/input for the password'''
    guess_list=[]
    print('>',)
    a,b,c,d,e=map(int, input().split())
    guess_list.append(a)
    guess_list.append(b)
    guess_list.append(c)
    guess_list.append(d)
    guess_list.append(e)
    return guess_list

def reportResult(password,guess):
    '''Reports users results, see if positions/numbers are correct'''
    numCorrect=0
    posNumCorrect=0
    for i in range(0,len(password)):
        for j in range(0,len(guess)):
            if(guess[j]==password[i]):
                numCorrect=numCorrect+1
        for i in range(0,len(password)):
            if(guess[i]==password[i]):
                posNumCorrect=posNumCorrect+1
        if(posNumCorrect==5):
             return True
        else:
            print(numCorrect," of 5 correct digits.")
            print(posNumCorrect," of 5 correct locations.")
            return False

def main():
    '''main function'''
    #Continue loop
    con="y"
    while(con=="y"):
        #set count=10
        guess_count=10
        #call pswd generator
        origin_pswd=generatePassword()
        print("I've set my password, enter 5 digits in the range [1-9] (e.g. 9 3 2 4 7):\n")
        print(origin_pswd) #used to test
        #loop unti 10 guess or correct guess
        while(guess_count!=0):
            print(guess_count," guesses remaining.")
            #get user input
            guess_list=getUserGuess()
            #Call check
            if(reportResult(origin_pswd,guess_list)):
                print("You got my treasure! Congratulations. You correctly geussed the password:",*origin_pswd)
                print()
                break;
            else:
                guess_count=guess_count-1
                if(guess_count==0):
                    print("You'll never get my treasure! The password was ",*origin_pswd)
                    print()
                    break;
        #Loop continuation prompt
        print("Would you like to play again?   (y/n) ")
        con=input("> ")
        while(con!="y" and con!="n"):
            print("Error!!!Please eneter y/n")
            ch=input("> ")
        if (con =="n"):
            print("Thanks for playing!")

#call main
if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

I think the problem will be in my reportResult function; I'm stuck.

Comment: Outside of the actual problem, I recommend that you look at "list comprehension".  You can use this to really shorten your code and make it easier to read through.

Comment: Cool, will totally check that out.

Comment: For instance, `get_user_guess` reduces to a single line: `return [int(_) for _ in input("> ").split()]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is improper indentation:

```
for i in range(0,len(password)):
    for j in range(0,len(guess)):
        if(guess[j]==password[i]):
            numCorrect=numCorrect+1
    for i in range(0,len(password)):
        if(guess[i]==password[i]):
            posNumCorrect=posNumCorrect+1
```

Your *outer* loop has an index of `i`, which you then hijack and alter in the second inner loop.  This drives `i` past the loop limit, exiting the outer loop on the first iteration.

You need to pull that second "inner" loop, and all subsequent code, back to its proper position, one indent to the left, *out* of the first loop.

```
def reportResult(password,guess):
    '''Reports users results, see if positions/numbers are correct'''
    numCorrect = 0
    posNumCorrect = 0
    for i in range(len(password)):
        for j in range(len(guess)):
            if(guess[j] == password[i]):
                numCorrect = numCorrect+1
    for i in range(len(password)):
        if(guess[i] == password[i]):
            posNumCorrect = posNumCorrect+1
    if(posNumCorrect == 5): 
        return True
    else:
        print(numCorrect," of 5 correct digits.")
        print(posNumCorrect," of 5 correct locations.")
        return False
```

Output:

```
I've set my password, enter 5 digits in the range [1-9] (e.g. 9 3 2 4 7):

[8, 2, 4, 5, 6]
10  guesses remaining.
> 8 3 4 5 6
4  of 5 correct digits.
4  of 5 correct locations.
9  guesses remaining.
> 3 8 4 6 5
4  of 5 correct digits.
1  of 5 correct locations.
8  guesses remaining.
>
```

Comment: Did not see that when I was skimming through my code. Thanks so much!